# Java generics and reflection: class loading

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I am given some classes that are unknown to me. Some of them are shown as an example:

```
class Paper {}

class Bakery {}

class Cake extends Bakery {}

class ReflexiveBaker {

  /**
   * Create bakery of the provided class.
   * 
   * @param order class of bakery to create
   * @return bakery object
   */
  public Object bake(Class order) {
    // Add implementation here
  }

}
```

The task is to redesign method signature types if needed and to add implementation. The bake method should conform to the following:

- Create objects of class Bakery or any subclass of it according to class argument
- Flag compile-time error if order argument is not Bakery or any subclass of it (e.g. if it is Paper or Object)

Whatever I've tried I'm getting an error:
Main.java:: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Cake
            Cake cake = baker.bake(Cake.class);

The best I've come up with is this:

```
public Object bake(Class<? extends Bakery> order) throws Exception {
        return order.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
}
```

I know that it's wrong but I'm completely stuck here. Could someone please explain what's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your methods return type is `java.lang.Object` and the compiler can't vouch that the return value is of type `Cake` unless you convince the compiler by adding an explicit unchecked cast like this.

```
Cake cake = (Cake) ReflexiveBaker.bake(Cake.class);
```

This unchecked cast is error prone and awkward. Say you have another class called Bread that is a subtype of `Bakery` and you pass that class instance expecting Cake as the return type. The above statement still compiles, but throws a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

A much better approach is to generify the method using a bounded type parameter such a way that it accepts only sub types of `Bakery` and returns the same type as the type parameter of the class object provided. Here's one such attempt.

```
static class ReflexiveBaker {
    public static <T extends Bakery> T bake(Class<T> order) {
        try {
            return order.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                    | InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new AssertionError("Class could not be instantiated.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
That's what I thought. But doesn't it violate the conditions of the task?
Because it does not only redesign the method signature, but also the return type of the method?

Comment: It does violate the conditions of the task, but for a good reason. This version is much more type safe and less prone to errors than the one that merely returns `java.lang.Object`

Comment: I understand now. Thanks a lot for your help!
Really appreciate it!

Comment: There’s not much sense in catching all those meaningful exceptions, to print a meaningless `"Class could not be instantiated."` message and throw an `AssertionError` carrying even less information. Why don’t you `throw new AssertionError("Class could not be instantiated.", e);` within the `catch` clause?

Comment: Makes sense, I was thinking about a better approach. Thanks for pointing that out. Let me update the answer accordingly. In fact, I was about to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` with that information.

Comment: Well, you could also use `throw new IllegalArgumentException("Class could not be instantiated.", e);` instead. Note that the `// Can't get here.` is truly unreachable, so it will raise a compiler error unless you remove that obsolete `throw new AssertionError();` statement.

Comment: Good catch, I have updated the answer removing that obsoleted line of code. Appreciate it. Thanks !